# Sí misma / usted misma

Tags: pronombres, objetos-indirectos

En la siguiente oración, cómo es correcto:

> (En una tienda)
>
> ¿(Usted) lo quiere para **usted** misma?

o

> ¿(Usted) lo quiere para **sí** misma?

What my research says: the grammar I'm using (Gramática de uso del español C1-C2, page 46), says that `mismo` is used with `usted` and `ustedes`; however, they fail to provide a single example of this so I don't really know how it is supposed to be used. I asked my teacher (madrileña) and she says both sounds Ok for her, but has to check. So I really don't know, but it might be one of those things that have a rule, but nobody complies with them in the real world.

Comment: Not answering your question really, but if I were to say that, I would just go for the simpler "¿Es para usted?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the correct form is

> ¿Lo quiere para **usted** misma?

Take into account that *usted* uses 3rd person conjugation but refers to "second person" (stands for tú/vosotros). The relexive pronoun `sí` is a 3rd person pronoun. See [here](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XmOP8Ia|XmQKxT2)

> pron. person. 3.ª pers. m. y f. Forma reflexiva de los pronombres él, ella, ellos, ellas, precedida siempre de preposición.

If you ask someone

> ¿Lo quiere para **sí** misma?

is equivalent of

> ¿Lo quiere para **ella** misma?

If you were not addressing the person *de usted* you clearly would had asked

> ¿Lo quieres para **ti** misma?

Which is a second person. You don't need to switch to third person just to be polite, it is just sometinh the *usted* fomr does in the conjugations. The *usted* form uses 3rd person conjugations, but the use of `sí` and `usted` are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Diego doesn't fit with what I learned in Mexico.  I learned to say "sí misma" for objects, i.e. complements (not objects in the sense of *things*) -- and "usted misma" for subjects, for example, "Hágalo usted mismo" which corresponds to DIY projects (*do it yourself*).

I wondered if this was a regionalism.  But I found a [psychology article](https://elpais.com/elpais/2018/08/10/eps/1533900395_612761.html) in the Spanish publication *El País Semanal* with the title:

> ¿Usted se quiere a sí mismo?

And along with this comes *consigo mismo/misma* (which is also in the article).

By Diego's reasoning, logically, there would never be a *consigo mismo*, since he concluded that objects need to be *usted mismo*, which would then give us "con usted mismo."

(I agree with @charlie that in this particular example, we don't really need so much -- but there are situations, such as this article title, that do.)